# How to handle selenium python script when element is already present on page?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am scraping a small site wherein I loop to send_keys to a textbox then click on the search button, the page loads some results, I check for presence_of_element and finally I get text of those results.
But the issue is when the site opens it already has a few results Present on the page, so when the loop for the search starts and the search button is clicked, the page takes a few secs to load the New Results but the script continues and selenium see the presence of initial results and captures them again and the loop continues with the same result. I tried adding time.sleep but still runs into some issues. Below is the workflow and code

```
URL Opens
Result 0 already present on page
Change Dropdown
Loop starts>>
Text sent to searchBox >> Search button Clicked
Result 0 still present on Site
Page is loading >> But Selenium sees presence of Result0 and gets text
Loop continues to send new key and click search button
Page is still loading with Result 1>> selenium again checks presence and this continues.
```

---

```
self.driver.get(self.url)
self.waitForPresenceOfElement(locator=self.radius_drop_down, locatorType='id')
self.dropByType(data='100', locator=self.radius_drop_down, locatorType='id', type='value')
time.sleep(6)
for state in self.states:
    self.sendKeysWhenReady(data=state, locator=self.search_box, locatorType='id')
    time.sleep(1)
    self.elementClick(locator=self.search_button, locatorType='xpath')
    time.sleep(3)
    if self.getElementList(self.storesXpath, locatorType='xpath'):  # to ignore Empty states
        stores = self.waitForPresenceOfAllElements(locator=self.storesXpath, locatorType='xpath')
        for store in stores:  
            self.full_list.append(self.getText(element=store).lower())
```

Comment: It seems we are missing large parts of your code. What is `self.radius_drop_down`; or `self.waitForPresenceOfElement()`, `sendKeysWhenReady()`...

Comment: count the elements. find_elements will return all occurrences and you can keep track by the size of list returned.

Comment: @C.Peck this code consists of custom functions that were written, so things like radius_drop_down is just a locator, self.waitForPresenceOfElement() is a custom method which checks for presence of element. Not sure if all that code is even relevant here. the issue is when element click happens the page takes a few secs to load but the script moves forward and finds the Already present elements and thats causing the issue

Comment: You should consider using like a `waitForElementToBeClickable(element)`, which is a stronger check than weighting for the presence of the element. (It confirms the element is present, displayed, and enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you fix this is to:

1. Start your loop.
2. Find an existing search result on the page and get a reference to it.

   ```
   result = driver.find_element(...)
   ```
3. Send the search terms and click Search.
4. Wait for the `result` reference to be stale, that tells you that the page is reloading.

   ```
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    wait.until(EC.staleness_of(result))
   ```
5. Wait for results to be visible and continue looping.